# Is it a good idea to make 1 million individual http requests to a service from a kafka consumer?

Tags: java, http, httprequest, scalability, distributed-system

Let's say, I have a kakfa consumer which can consume tons of messages per sec. Each of these messages need to be posted to another service via http request. Is it a good idea to make individual http request for each message? Something like 1 million messages = 1 million http requests

Comment: Probably no.  But that's not really what you need to know, is it.

Answer (score 0):

This largely depends on your use case. Obviously batching them will be more efficient. However, I think the most important thing to remember is when you commit these messages. Whenever you decide to make the http call, I would recommend not committing the message until the http call succeeds. Of course this implies that your http call is idempotent because if your app crashes during the http request, you will consume the message again.